# How to convert to a list after using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, computer-science

This is my .csv file generated using pandas. I am wanting to convert back to list type for the column of 'age' and 'studies'. But the '''dp.types''' show the type of age is '''object'''. All the elements are string, '[' '6' '8' ,'8' '3' ']'. Does anyone know how to convert back to the normal list with integer [68,83] 
[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Co6.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a column in pandas to a list use:

```py
# assuming df is your dataframe
df["column name"].to_numpy().to_list()
```

Which will first turn it into a `numpy` array and them the numpy array (where are only numbers) to a list
Or convert the whole column to numeric data type and then to a list:

```py
pd.to_numeric(df["column name"]).to_list()
```

Comment: Why `to_numpy`?

Comment: I read somewhere that `.to_list()` may try to convert it into strings. Converting first into `numpy` assures us its going to be numbers

Comment: Just use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)